# Why Python for web development?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if learning this language or not.

I've been 15 years mainly coding with PHP. I know C, C++, Java, Perl … but PHP has solved all of my problems for web development.

I've read carefully this: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonVsPhp

I find Python useful for sysadmin tasks for example, or for first programming language learning. Sincerely, I love its cleanliness and clarity (it's like a "Jquerized PHP") … but I'm still finding blogs defending Python for web development … Why ?

Can anyone explain me advantages of Python for web ?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer because it's not very substantial, but some people just like Python better.

Comment: Because the most important thing for a language is to efficiently use developer time, and Python is better at that than PHP (in the long run) even for web development. This is not an appropriate question for this site -- please read the first two FAQ sections -- what questions to ask and what questions __not__ to ask.

Comment: @agf that's impossible to say, I'm sure there are plenty of really good PHP programmers that could write circles around mediocre python developers, would you recommend they throw everything they know to "start over"? the point is the language is just the tool, the skill of the programmer is what most effects time efficiency, not that it takes 10 characters instead of 15.

Answer (score 22):

I wouldn't do Python web dev without a framework. Having moved from Rails to Django, Django is much better. It has great docs, a great community, doesn't try to force architecture (which can lead to hours of googling about where to put things), and doesn't hide things behind unnerving "magic" the way Rails does.

It secures against XSS by default (i.e. you have to tell it NOT to escape HTML) and since it has a great ORM interface there's little chance of silly SQL injection mistakes. Also has built-in protection against CSRF attacks which operates as middleware. It's not that PHP is inherently insecure, but it gives the developers too many opportunities to mess up.

It also has amazing extensions like Pinax and they integrate essential extensions into their core every release.

You should also not underestimate the psychological benefits of coding in a beautiful language.

Comment: This sounds very much like a plug. And I'm loving it ;p.

Comment: Can't help it, I fell in love with it :p

Comment: you're comparing a language to a fully fledged kitchen sink framework... apples and oranges man.

Comment: I was ready to downvote any answers to this question since it's obviously not constructive / off topic -- but I can't downvote this.

Comment: @bcouhlan Yeah... you are comparing language to a framework. PHP also has a framework called **Laravel** that does everything you mentioned above and more. I would still love to see why choose Python over PHP for web.